# c++ how do i get ifstream::get() working if i want to split it into words?

Tags: c++, fstream

Here's my code. I keep getting errors at the line where I call `get()`. I'm trying to use delimiters:

```
char* spamdir = argv[1];

char* hamdir = argv[2];
char* dictname = argv[3];
ofstream* outp = new ofstream;
ifstream* read = new ifstream;
DIR *sdp = opendir(spamdir);
struct dirent *directory;
char* word = (char*)malloc(256);
while(directory = readdir(sdp))
{
    cout << directory->d_name << endl;
    char* name = directory->d_name;
    char* filepath = (char*) malloc(100);
    strcpy(filepath,"\0");
    strcat(filepath,spamdir);
    strcat(filepath,"/");
    strcat(filepath,name);
    read->open(filepath);
    if(read->good())
        cout <<"sweet\n";

    while(read->good())
    {
        read->get(word,255," ");
        cout << word  << endl;
    }
    read->close();
    free(filepath);
}
```

Comment: 1. What is the code doing? 2. What do you want it to do? 3. Why are you allocating istream and ostream objects with `new` when there's no reason to? 4. Why not use `std::string` if you're going to be using iostreams?

Comment: 5. Why use `malloc` when you're using C++?

Answer (score 2):

You don't tell us what the error is, but my guess is that the problem is that the delimiter argument in `std::istream::get()` needs to be a `char`, but you are passing a string.  Try using `' '` instead of `" "`.

An easier way to do this is to use `std::getline()`, something like this:

```
std::string word;
while (std::getline(*read, word, ' ')) {
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
}
```

Any time you use `malloc` in a C++ program, you are probably doing things the hard way.

(BTW, whenever you have compiler error messages, it is a good idea to include those messages in your question.)